# Qt 5.7 IMX6 compilation

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to compile Qt 5.7 for my imx6 platform and I have a problem with opengl.

Yocto + meta-qt5

Error msg:

```
/usr/include/GLES2/gl2.h:67:25: note: previous declaration as 'typedef khronos_ssize_t GLsizeiptr'
 typedef khronos_ssize_t GLsizeiptr;
                         ^
usr/include/qt5/QtGui/qopenglext.h:475:19: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef ptrdiff_t GLintptr'
 typedef ptrdiff_t GLintptr;
                   ^
usr/include/GLES2/gl2.h:68:26: note: previous declaration as 'typedef khronos_intptr_t GLintptr'
 typedef khronos_intptr_t GLintptr;
                          ^
```

Does someone know what I can do with this?